# How to restore whole view of fragment on back button pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I need to pull data from server for the first time. When back `button` pressed from another `fragment`, previous view should be restored but not recreate the view again and pull the data from server again.
Part of my `fragment` is as follows:

**AttendanceFragment.cs**

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            .......
            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AttendanceListview, container, false);
            } 
           .........
           // this is where I get data from WebServer
           GetClassSection(); // I am confused here where to put this method and pull data from server



            listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;




            return rootView;
          }

 public override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.PutString("_dataGotFromServer", dataGotFromServer);
    }
```

While landing onto this `fragment` from `button` click 
I have replaced `fragment` this way

```
 public void ReplaceFragment(Context context, Fragment newFragment, string TAG)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).SupportFragmentManager;
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, newFragment);
        ft.AddToBackStack(TAG);
        ft.Commit();

    }
```

**BaseAdapter** *is initialized here*

```
 public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dataList = new List<DA_ClassSectionAttendance>();
        attendanceAdapter = new AttendanceListAdapter(this.Activity, dataList);


        // Create your fragment here
        //set whether MenuOption show/hide from toolbar
        HasOptionsMenu = true;
    }
```

and **my Adapter is set here**

```
  public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       dataGotFromServer = savedInstanceState.GetString("_dataGotFromServer");  // savedInstanceState always gets null here  

        listView.Adapter = attendanceAdapter;
    }
```

and my data are pulled from server and updated in ui

```
 private async void GetClassSection()
    {
        try
        { ...........

            Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () => {
                await Task.Delay(1 * 100);

                attendanceAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            });

        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> When back button pressed from another fragment, previous view should be restored but not recreate the view again and pull the data from server again.

When press a back button,  if you don't want your fragment restore data and recreate the view, using `FragmentTransaction.Add()` method instead of   `FragmentTransaction.Replace()` will be a better choice.

When you use `Replace` method, it will replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling `Remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same `containerViewId` and then `Add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments given here. So when you want reuse some fragment, you have to think about restore data, it will be a little complex.

But when you use `Add` method, it will  add a `fragment` to the activity state. This `fragment` may optionally also have its `view` (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the `activity`. This means the previous `Fragment` just hide, when you want to show the previous `fragment`, there is no need for you to worry about how to restore data.

Here is my code :

```
public void ReplaceFragment(Context context, Fragment newFragment, string TAG)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).SupportFragmentManager;
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        //When you want to show your AttendanceFragment
        if (newFragment == null)
        {
            newFragment = new AttendanceFragment();
        }
        if (newFragment.IsAdded)
        {
            ft.Show(mg);
        }
        else
        {
            newFragment.Add(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, newFragment);
        }
        if (anotherFragmentInstance != null && anotherFragmentInstance.IsAdded)
        {
            ft.Hide(anotherFragmentInstance);
        }
        ft.AddToBackStack(TAG);
        ft.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: @Ishwor Khanal, is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this image](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle), try `OnActivityCreated` on the fragment class.